# c# Lambda expression for next and previous dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda

I have following database table 'Date':

```
DateId      Date
1       08/05/2012
2       08/01/2012
3       08/25/2012
4       08/15/2012
5       08/22/2012
.....
```

To get most recent date i am using following expression:

```
var recentDate = db.Date.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can i use recentDate to get previous date or next date using lambda expressions?

When i try to use latestDate i get an error saying:

```
operator > cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'App.Models.Date
```

this is what i am trying for previous date:

```
var previous date = top10Date.Where(d => d.Date > latestDate).OrderBy(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

is above expression right? how can i make this work?

Comment: That looks good to me other than that you may need to use `OrderByDescending`

Comment: Except that latestDate is of type App.Models.Date, whereas App.Models.Date.Date is of type DateTime, which is what OP is trying to compare.

Comment: To get the `recentDate`, Don't sort  since it is O(n*Log(n)) operation. Just use `db.Date.Max(d => d.Date)` which can be  completed in `O(n)` time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare DateTime to App.Models.Date, which the compiler does not know how to compare.

You are probably trying to do the following:

```
var previous date = top10Date.Where(d => d.Date > latestDate.Date).OrderBy(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recentDate is not a DateTime, it is the entire Date object... just Select the Date part and you'll be bringing back less data as well.

```
var recentDate = db.Date.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).Select(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```